# Scroll issue if there are many images almost unusable in some devices

Tags: codenameone

The whole screen is filled with images jst like facebook home screen. If there are fewer no of images, it works alright. But as soon as more images for instance 50 images. The app stuck for a no of time while scrolling in android devices. It seems like as if there is a vibration in the images. In samsung (j7 prime) this prob is lower but noticeable & seems quite uncomfortable in other samsung devices & it creates uneasiness for the user. However in some other devices I've tested for eg in Gionee mobiles (S6s), the app is almost unplayable. The scrolling is very very difficult, almost unscrollable.

My demo code

```
    mainContainer = new Container (new BoxLayout (BoxLayout.y ()));

    for (String imgUrl : allImages){
      Image singleImg =  URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "small_" + imgObject + k, imgObject.toString(), URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);
      Button b = new Button (singleImg);
      mainContainer.add (b);
    }
```

Update 1: I've changed placeholder size to screen size & added 2 btns with same images, so that there are quite large no. of images. Then the same problem as above is seen when I built the kitchen sink app again.

```
if (placeholder == null) {
    Image placeholderTmp = Image.createImage(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), 0);
    if (Display.getInstance().isGaussianBlurSupported()) {
        placeholderTmp = Display.getInstance().gaussianBlurImage(placeholderTmp, 10);
    } else {
        placeholderTmp = placeholderTmp.modifyAlpha((byte) 100);
    }
    placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(placeholderTmp, true);
}
InfiniteContainer ic = new InfiniteContainer(10) {
    List items;
    List allItems = new ArrayList();
    String nextURL = WEBSERVICE_URL;

    @Override
    public Component[] fetchComponents(int index, int amount) {
        if (index == 0) {
            nextURL = WEBSERVICE_URL;
        }
        if (nextURL == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest(nextURL) {
            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                items = null;
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                Map response = parser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
                items = (List) response.get("items");
                nextURL = (String) response.get("nextPage");
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleException(Exception err) {
                Log.e(err);
                Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                    ToastBar.showErrorMessage("An error occured while connecting to the server: " + err);
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
                Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                    ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Error code from the server: " + code + "\n" + message);
                });
            }

        };
        req.setPost(false);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);

        if (items == null) {
            return null;
        }

        allItems.addAll(items);

        Component[] result = new Component[items.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            for (int iter = 0; iter < result.length; iter++) {
                Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) items.get(iter);
                String title = (String) m.get("title");
                String details = (String) m.get("details");
                String url = (String) m.get("url");
                String thumb = (String) m.get("thumb");
                URLImage thumbImage = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), thumb, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
                ScaleImageButton btn = new ScaleImageButton(thumbImage);
                ScaleImageButton btn1 = new ScaleImageButton(thumbImage);
                ScaleImageButton btn2 = new ScaleImageButton(thumbImage);
                btn.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
                btn.getAllStyles().setMarginBottom(8);
                btn1.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
                btn1.getAllStyles().setMarginBottom(8);
                btn2.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
                btn2.getAllStyles().setMarginBottom(8);
                result[iter] = BoxLayout.encloseY(btn,btn1,btn2);
            }
        }
        Layout l = getLayout();
        if (l instanceof GridLayout) {
            int cmps = getComponentCount() - 1 + result.length;
            int extra = 0;
            if (cmps % 3 != 0) {
                extra = 1;
            }
            setLayout(new GridLayout(cmps / 3 + extra, 3));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here I have added the buttons in the mainContainer and saw nothing to improve on performance related solutions. Is there anything else I have to look for? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the dogs demo in the kitchen sink & the performance section in the developer guide.

Also have a look at the Contacts demo within the kitchen sink where we lazily load the information.

Every `URLImage` would perform a download/lazyload both of which will stutter the UI potentially and you need to queue that & deal with it.

Comment: I saw kitchen sink webService, It works fine in devices. But I changed the placeholder size(height & width) fit to screen size,& increase the no. of images in the kitchen sink page. And then the same problem is seen. I've updated the code changed in update 1 above.

Comment: If you have a huge number of full page images scrolling you are thrashing the GC a lot. You need to optimize image usage and do a lot of low level work for this kind of UI to work smoothly.

Comment: how can I optimize image usage? I didnt get it. See the video of kitchen sink demo I customized. (update 1 code above) https://youtu.be/r0_NKdGlluo The scrolling stucks many times & there is a vibration like thing going on... downloadUrlToStorageInBackground solves the scrolling problem but the drawback is - it downloads & replaces the images everytime the screen is opened & no caching 2. What I didnt get is: after loading all the images lets say after 10 mins the app is opened, why is it having difficult time to load images again?(not jst when screen opens at 1st bt aftr long period of tim 2)

Comment: I suggest you go over the performance section in the developer guide, pay close attention to the image locking explanation and use a profiler to see what is really triggering the issues.

Comment: Hi Beck. I am running into a similar problem. I used cloudinary to scale and size the images server-side and that helped with performance but the scroll is still a bit jittery. I noticed that cloudinary uses URLImage.createToStorage which uses Util.downloadImageToStorage . Did you manage to build a working example with downloadImageToStorageInBackground or did that give you the same problem? I wonder if it is the writing to file storage that is slowing down the UI or is it the call to setIcon. Did you manage to solve your problem and could you please post your downloadImageToStorage code ?